# Wordpress local admin redirects to live server admin page

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Just transfer my live server wordpress website. Everything wprks fine when i realize that the locally localhost/site/wp-admin is redirecting in the live one.

And i can't access locally website.

What should i do to fix this, and work locally to do some experiments?

Thats the sql commands i put after transferring database locally

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value,'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

 UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');

 UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following in wp-config.php to fix this:

```
define('DOMAIN_ROOT', 'http://localhost/site');
define('WP_HOME', DOMAIN_ROOT);
define('WP_SITEURL', DOMAIN_ROOT);
```

Comment: Thank you my friend.. Fixed you awesome

Answer (score 1):

Use this script: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to replace all occurrences of your live website url with the ones for the local website.

It will also apply the replace on serialized data in the db, so everything should be fine after doing this.